# How can I use a JSON token without making a db call every time I want to access a restricted resource?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, redux, passport.js

I'm new to authentication and I'm building an app using React, Redux, Passport.js, MongoDB and Express.

I'm following the tutorial at https://jonathanmh.com/express-passport-json-web-token-jwt-authentication-beginners/ to set up authentication using the Passport.js 'jwt' strategy. The code below is executed every time a user requests a resource. As you can see, a db call (fake) is emitted to find the user's id.

```
var jwtOptions = {}
jwtOptions.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
jwtOptions.secretOrKey = 'tasmanianDevil';

var strategy = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, next) {
  console.log('payload received', jwt_payload);

  // usually this would be a database call:
  var user = users[_.findIndex(users, {id: jwt_payload.id})];
  if (user) {
    next(null, user);
  } else {
    next(null, false);
  }
});

passport.use(strategy);
```

The issue I have is that every time a request is sent to a resource, a database query is emitted. From what I understand, the whole point of using JSON tokens is to prevent db calls. So is there a way of using tokens without touching the database? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "emmitted?" A database call is made for the requested resource?

Comment: Hi @Galupuf, yep that's right! I just mean a database call is made :) Any idea on how to avoid the db call when using tokens?

Comment: Gotcha. You can't avoid a DB call for the requested resource, as you will always need to fetch that (especially if that resource varies for each user). JWTs allow you to save on db calls because you don't need to query it with their credentials to verify identity for each request

Comment: I see, interesting! So the token already contains the user's info so there's no need for an additional db call. That makes sense to me. Thanks for the clarification @Galupuf :)

Comment: Exaclty :) If I added an answer could you accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid a DB call for the requested resource, as you will always need to fetch that (especially if that resource varies for each user).

JWTs allow you to save on db calls because you don't need to query it with their credentials to verify identity for each request.

If anyone has anything else to add to this please let me know :)